# Automatically set Grid.Row in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, row

In a form, I have a large grid, say 30 rows, 14 columns. I want to add some additional info in between, say in between row 4 and 5. After I added this, I need to update the following rows' Grid.Row property. Is there a way to automatically set the row to next instead of static? That acts something like  in HTML.

I also tried with a stack panel, with each row wrapped in a grid. With this, I could achieve the result, but I need to add lot of code, like column definitions. Alternatively, is it possible to apply the column definitions from style?

Comment: Do you wish to display data or Controls in your Grid?

Comment: Controls in this case. But looking for a generic solution that can be applied to any case.